# Generating Canvas width and height attributes to be the same size as a rectangle of user inputted size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The code below, on start up, generates a rectangle the same size as the canvas which is correct. The problem is that when the user clicks the button a new canvas is generated but the rectangle does not appear. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ <!-- function to change the <canvas> attributes of "width" and "height" to the same size as the rectangle -->
   $("#btn").click(function(){
   $("#myCanvas").attr("height", $("#height").val());
   $("#myCanvas").attr("width", $("#width").val());
  });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  &nbsp;Rectangle Width:
  <input type="number" id="width" value="400">
  &nbsp;Rectangle Height:
  <input type="number" id="height" value="400">
  &nbsp;    
  <br>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width=400 height=400 style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;"> 
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
rect();
function rect(){
  width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.strokeRect(0,0, width, height);
}
</script>
<button id="btn" onclick = "rect()">Submit to draw a rectangle the same size as the canvas</button>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove your `$(document).ready(function(){` function and then change your function  `rect()` as below:-

```
 function rect(){ 
   width = document.getElementById("width").value;
   height = document.getElementById("height").value;
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.canvas.height = height;//add this 
   ctx.canvas.width = width;// and this
   ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
   ctx.strokeRect(0,0, width, height);
```

}

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/12/)

Comment: you might want to add that it was the resize that was clearing the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the rect function you are getting the id of width, I'm not really sure what that actually would resolve to.

```
width = document.getElementById("width").value;
```

but in the button click you are creating an attribute separate from the id called "width" and that changes does change the dimensions of the canvas.
If you don't want to get the heights and widths by jquery, you would use

```
document.getElementById("myCanvas").height
document.getElementById("myCanvas").width
```

try those in you code to change the height and width variables respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code inside the `onclick` attribute is executed before the listener defined with jQuery (`$("#btn").click(function(){...});`). So, when you click on the submit button, the `rect` function is called before the dimensions of the canvas element are changed, therefore the canvas content is emptied. You need to call `rect` after the canvas size changes:  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TRzMAfrjmHsDjUxXJngX).